Does Numpy return view or copy when combining slicing and advanced indexing?
The following snippet:
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
print(x.base)
y = x[:2, [0, 2]]
print(y.base)

outputs
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 24]
[[0 5]
 [2 7]]

From the docs I couldn't understand whether y should be view or copy. Any ideas why y is a view and why its base is different than x's?
Another example:
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
>>> x[:2, [0,2]].base
array([[0, 5],
       [2, 7]])
>>> x[[0,2], :2].base
>>> 

Is this behavior anywhere documented so a user can predict whether the output of a mixed (advanced+basic indexing) operation will be a view or copy?

In your doc link it says the dimensions resulting from the advanced indexing operation come first in the result array, and the subspace dimensions after that  That describes your y.base.  Since the slice is not in the middle, it can transpose that base to give y.

@hpaulj the dimensions resulting from the advanced indexing operation come first. What does this mean?

Try y = x[:3, [0, 2]] and look at y.base.shape.  (2,3)  The 2 is the advanced indexing dimension, 3 is from the slicing.

@hpaulj Thanks for this comment! Indeed y is the transpose of y.base. Since y.base is reserved only for y, the user  shouldn't worry modifying y, right?

Yes it's safe to modify y.  I think the fact that y.base isn't None onlly matters if some operation expects y to be c-contiguours.  Then it might have to do a further copy.

From the docs: ndarray.base

Base object if memory is from some other object.

Building arrays in steps
>>> xbase = np.arange(25)
>>> xbase.base is None
True
>>>
>>> x = xbase.reshape(5,5)
>>> x.base is xbase
True

reshape() returns a view so modifying x or its slices will alter xbase too
>>> x2 = x[2:]
>>> x2.base is xbase
True
>>> x2[-1][0] = 7777
>>> xbase
array([   0,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,   10,
         11,   12,   13,   14,   15,   16,   17,   18,   19, 7777,   21,
         22,   23,   24])

Advanced indexing returns a copy

Advanced indexing always returns a copy of the data (contrast with basic slicing that returns a view).

>>> y = x[:2, [0, 2]]
>>> y.base is xbase
False
>>> x2[-1][0] = 7777
>>> y[0][0] = 9999
>>> xbase
array([   0,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,   10,
         11,   12,   13,   14,   15,   16,   17,   18,   19, 7777,   21,
         22,   23,   24])

xbase remained unaltered after y changes.
Finally:

y is not a view of another object and its base is not the same as the source object.

Interestingly enough y.base is not None and any changes are reflected in its base
>>> y.base is None
False
>>> y.base
array([[0, 5],
       [2, 7]])

>>> y[0][0] = 9999
>>> y
array([[9999,    2],
       [   5,    7]])
>>> y.base
array([[9999,    5],
       [   2,    7]])


"Interestingly enough y.base is not None". This is exactly what I don't get. If it is considered advanced indexing the it should return a copy and not a view.

y is the transpose of its base.  The base is a copy, without connection to x.   Apparently it is easier, under the covers, to extract that base, and then transpose it for the end user.  That's an implementation detail, and not documented (that I know of).

@AntoniosSarikas advanced indexing in fact returns a copy. Its base would be the source object otherwise; that's what I tried to show. In other words, views can be detected by its base as it is the case with x and x2 objects.

@LMC So we don't need to worry whether we modify y since its base is only conserved for y (i.e. isn't shared with anything else)?

@AntoniosSarikas Correct. See the note that recommends copy() in some cases.

The indexing returns a copy, not a view (see: Can I get a view of a numpy array at specified indexes? (a view from "fancy indexing")). This is why .base gives different outputs

Can you elaborate please? Is the operation equivalent to x[adv_idx][slc]? Is advanced indexing always performed first before the slicing operation?

I'll try to illustrate what's happening with several mixes of basic and advanced indexing.
In [27]: x = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)

x.base is the flat 1d from arange.
Your case - slice followed by advanced:
In [28]: y = x[:3,[0,1]]; y, y.base
Out[28]: 
(array([[ 0,  1],
        [ 5,  6],
        [10, 11]]),
 array([[ 0,  5, 10],
        [ 1,  6, 11]]))

I changed the slice to 3 to make the transpose of the base more obvious.  It looks a bit like it took the [0,1] advanced index first, and 'tacked' the slice dimension after.  But the details of the compiled code could be different.
In the case of mixed advanced/basic with a slice in the middle, it can't unambiguously transpose the base, and so it leaves the base as is.
The reverse:
In [29]: y = x[[0,1,2],:2]; y, y.base
Out[29]: 
(array([[ 0,  1],
        [ 5,  6],
        [10, 11]]),
 None)

With advanced indexing first, the 'base' copy is already in the right shape, and doesn't need further transposing.
Pure slice:
In [30]: y = x[:3,:2]; y, y.base
Out[30]: 
(array([[ 0,  1],
        [ 5,  6],
        [10, 11]]),
 array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
        17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]))

This is a view - of the orignal arange.
Pure advanced:
In [32]: y = x[[[0],[1],[2]],[0,1]]; y, y.base
Out[32]: 
(array([[ 0,  1],
        [ 5,  6],
        [10, 11]]),
 None)

Broadcasting applies, combining a (3,1) with (2,) to produce the desired (3,2).
np.shares_memory or np.may_share_memory might be better tests than y.base is None.  See their help for details.
